# Regular Expression that checks first Character

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I need to do the following check:

- The first character is either an alphabetical character or _
- All other characters are either alphabetic, numeric, or _

I tried:

```
^('A'..'Z' | '_') ('A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')*
```

But it complains that it doesn't know what '^' is. So how can I check what it starts with in ANTLR?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Remove the ^ char (which is denoting a match starting at the beginning of a line in regular expressions) and that should be it.

Comment: @aurora91 Also to add to the answer, antlr lexer does not work like that with regex. It looks at the input in chunks not in terms of lines. So it would match that pattern with the rest of the text regardless of where it starts. (I think so at least)